# How to assign entries in a dataframe to different groups?

Tags: r, grouping, dataframe

So, in my df there is a column with all the subjects that I tested for an experiment. The entries are coded as a factor with x levels. Each subject has been tested twice, ergo there are two data-sets for each subject in the df. These data sets can be of different length. Now I need to group the subjects by time of testing (1 or 2), so I can include time as a fixed effect in my model. How can I do that?

Here is my little example df:

```
require("stringr")
>Subject<- c("DG_120204", "DG_120204", "DG_120305", "BZ_120407", "BZ_120506", "BZ_120506",     "BZ_120506", "SN_120310", "SN_120412")
s2<- str_extract(Subject, "\\d{6}")
dates<-as.Date(s2, format="%y%m%d") 
df<-data.frame(Subject, dates)


    Subject      dates
1 DG_120204 2012-02-04
2 DG_120204 2012-02-04
3 DG_120305 2012-03-05
4 BZ_120407 2012-04-07
5 BZ_120506 2012-05-06
6 BZ_120506 2012-05-06
7 BZ_120506 2012-05-06
8 SN_120310 2012-03-10
9 SN_120412 2012-04-12
```

For example, The first 2 entries for Subject DG are from testing session 1, the third line is session 2, the 4th line is session 1 for subject BZ, the 5th-7th lines are session 2 for BZ, and so on.

My idea would be to add another factor column (df$time) and fill it with 1's and 2's based on the levels of df$Subject (and the date-values in df$dates?). But right now I don't even get that far.

So I should have something like this:

```
    Subject      dates time
1 DG_120204 2012-02-04    1
2 DG_120204 2012-02-04    1
3 DG_120305 2012-03-05    2
4 BZ_120407 2012-04-07    1
5 BZ_120506 2012-05-06    2
6 BZ_120506 2012-05-06    2
7 BZ_120506 2012-05-06    2
8 SN_120310 2012-03-10    1
9 SN_120412 2012-04-12    2
```

I know this is another very basic question, please bear with me! I will learn this eventually...

Comment: Maybe I'm just dense, but I don't see the connection between the date and the time? How do you know which dates correspond to time == 1 and time == 2? If you know that, then look at `ifelse()` and perhaps `transform()` for tidyness.

Comment: @Chase: I only know it because the earlier testing date is session 1 and the later testing date is session 2.But, the dates are different for each subject. I will check out the functions you suggested...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a column for the subject 
(for the moment, it is apparently just a substring of the first column),
then add a column indicating if it is a new date (1) or not (0),
and then just cumulatively count the date changes.

```
df$id <- str_replace(df$Subject, "_.*", "") 
library(plyr)
df <- df[ order(df$Subject), ]
ddply(df, "id", mutate, 
  new  = c(1, dates[-1] != dates[-length(dates)]), 
  time = cumsum(new)
)

#     Subject      dates id new time
# 1 BZ_120407 2012-04-07 BZ   1    1
# 2 BZ_120506 2012-05-06 BZ   1    2
# 3 BZ_120506 2012-05-06 BZ   0    2
# 4 BZ_120506 2012-05-06 BZ   0    2
# 5 DG_120204 2012-02-04 DG   1    1
# 6 DG_120204 2012-02-04 DG   0    1
# 7 DG_120305 2012-03-05 DG   1    2
# 8 SN_120310 2012-03-10 SN   1    1
# 9 SN_120412 2012-04-12 SN   1    2
```

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your data correctly, each unique 2 character identifier is a subject and each unique 6 digit number is a difference trial, correct? If so, this question is tailor made for `colsplit`.

```
> cbind(df, colsplit(df$Subject, '_', c('Subject_ID', 'Trial')))
    Subject      dates Subject_ID  Trial
1 DG_120204 2012-02-04         DG 120204
2 DG_120204 2012-02-04         DG 120204
3 DG_120305 2012-03-05         DG 120305
4 BZ_120407 2012-04-07         BZ 120407
5 BZ_120506 2012-05-06         BZ 120506
6 BZ_120506 2012-05-06         BZ 120506
7 BZ_120506 2012-05-06         BZ 120506
8 SN_120310 2012-03-10         SN 120310
9 SN_120412 2012-04-12         SN 120412
>
```

Now you have your subject ID and the trial number ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `split()` with a `for` loop does the trick:

```
require("stringr")
Subject<- c("DG_120204", "DG_120204", "DG_120305", "BZ_120407", "BZ_120506",
"BZ_120506", "BZ_120506", "SN_120310", "SN_120412")
s2 <- str_extract(Subject, "\\d{6}")
dates<-as.Date(s2, format="%y%m%d") 
df <- data.frame(Subject, dates)

# Add categorical variable:
spl <- split(df, f=df$Subject)
times <- 1:length(spl)
for(x in seq(along=times)) {
    spl[[x]]$time <- times[x]
}
df <- unsplit(spl, f=df$Subject)

# Sort based of 'Subject' column: 
df <- df[order(df$Subject),]
> df
    Subject      dates time
4 BZ_120407 2012-04-07   1
5 BZ_120506 2012-05-06   2
6 BZ_120506 2012-05-06   2
7 BZ_120506 2012-05-06   2
1 DG_120204 2012-02-04   3
2 DG_120204 2012-02-04   3
3 DG_120305 2012-03-05   4
8 SN_120310 2012-03-10   5
9 SN_120412 2012-04-12   6
```